# Erlang error when trying to run RabbitMQ

Tags: windows, erlang, installation, rabbitmq

I'm trying to install RabbitMQ with Erlang in Windows 7 64bit. I'm installing:

```
R16B01 Windows 64 Bit Binary File
rabbitmq-server-3.1.5.exe
```

Followed this tutorial step by step

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9wwZAuub1w
```

But when running the command: "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management"

This error shows up:

```
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},"Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.erlang
.cookie': enoent",[]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{auth,init,[
'Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.19.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{"Failed
to create cookie file 'z:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"
auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server
,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{f
ile,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl
"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]
}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.17.0>]},{d
ictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},
{reductions,951}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net
_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.er
lang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth
,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server
.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239
}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{res
tart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,ker
nel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,au
th,{"Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cooki
e,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]}
,{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do
_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{na
me,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{
shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application
_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0
.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,
net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'z:
/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{
auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_se
rver.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line
,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"ap
plication_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib
.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}
]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{
heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},{reductions,150}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,12},{13,23,53}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{
shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"
Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[
{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen
_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_appl
y,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type
,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kern
el,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,au
th,{\"Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.erlang.cookie': enoent\",[{auth,init_coo
kie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,
139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,i
nit_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[norm
al,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kerne
l,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,aut
h,{"Failed to create cookie file 'z:/.
```

Why is trying to reach Z:/ directory?? been searching for that in a config file but I couldn't find it.

Searched in Google but no answers worked for me.

Also i've set the environment variables: ERLANG_HOME and RABBITMQ_SERVER, where:

```
ERLANG_HOME: C:\Program Files\erl5.10.2

RABBITMQ_SERVER: C:\rabbitmq_server-3.1.5
```

Does anyone came across with this issue ? How did you guys resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17496037/113848), though it seems it never got a proper answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Create Cookie file RabbitMQ in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495874/failed-to-create-cookie-file-rabbitmq-in-windows)

Comment: Already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495874/failed-to-create-cookie-file-rabbitmq-in-windows/29018928#29018928

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this mailing list thread](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/RabbitMQ-on-Windows-XP-Failed-to-create-cookie-file-td10460.html), you need to set the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` environment variables such that they point to your home directory when concatenated.  Presumably `HOMEDRIVE` is set to `z:` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nevertheless, there was a problem with the executable installation of rabbitmq, used the .zip version, rebooted and it worked fine. Thanks for your help.