# Adding environment variable for erlang shows error in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

I installed erlang 19 for rabbitmq in Azure VM with windows 2016 OS. 
but it shows 'ERLANG HOME not set properly' while enabling rabbitMQ management plugin. 
I added environment variable in both system variable and user variable like 'ERLANG_HOME' with path 'C:\Program Files\erl8.2\

When I install the same in windows servfer 2012 R2. It works fine.

Is there any error in the way in which I set environment variable in windows server 2016. Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting `HOME` rather than `ERLANG_HOME`.

Comment: Tried with 'HOME' still it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue was able to resolve it with the solutions on this thread

[Windows x64 RabbitMQ install error with Erlang environment var (ERLANG_HOME)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323621/windows-x64-rabbitmq-install-error-with-erlang-environment-var-erlang-home)

For me the issue was windows didn't pick up the environment variable until restart.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an answer to this thread since it still does not have an accepted answer. When encountering the "ERLANG HOME not set properly" error, it is worth a shot to see if you opened CMD on Windows as an Adminsitrator when enabling the RabbitMQ management plugin. Hope this helps. :D