# RabbitMQ 3.6.6 on Windows 10 64-bit - Erlang not detected

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

I am running 64-bit Windows 10, I installed Erlang 64-bit R16B03, set-up ERLANG_HOME system env variable (not the user env var) and validated it to work OK from command shell.
When I run RabbitMQ3.6.6.exe to setup I get error "Erlang could not be detected". What version of Erlang do I need for RabbitMQ 3.6.6 ??
Does Erlang have to be installed in C:\Program Files??
I installed it in C:\Erlang folder.

I also tried to add %ERLANG_HOME%\bin to Path but it made no difference.
I have VC++ redistributable exe already installed (2005,2008,2013,2015).
I tried version OTP 19.2 (erl8.2) of Erlang with same results.
Any ideas?

I am trying to avoid installing manually from RabbitMQ zip file because I am new to RabbitMQ and just want to get it up and running so I can learn it.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323621/windows-x64-rabbitmq-install-error-with-erlang-environment-var-erlang-home#12323630) as it looks similar (duplicate?)

Comment: thanks. I read it before posting, it did not help me

Answer (score 5):

I got it working. Basically, setup does not work unless you install it in default C:\Program Files folder on Windows 10 64-bit. I had Erlang initially installed in C:\Erlang and even though ERLANG_HOME system var was correctly set up still did not work from RabbitMQ setup. Once I installed Erlang in C:\Program Files and ran ERLANG and RabbitMQ set-ups "run as administrator" then it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang should be installed in its default location C:\Program Files\erl8.3.
Once you have installed in the default location you have to set 
ERLANG_HOME and Path in your environment variables.

Only then the RabbitMQ installation will start.

Important note: Installing Erlang in other than the default location mentioned above will not work even if you have set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with *RabbitMQ 3.5.6* and *erlang 1.7*.
The *ERLANG_HOME* was set correctly but I couldn't install rabbitMQ as it said that couldn't find erlang.

I have removed erlang and install it again. But I run installation exe **as Administrator**.
And then I installed RabittMQ successfully.