# RabbitMQ3.9.11 - ERLANG_HOME not set correctly in windows 10

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-10, erlang

I have installed RabbitMQ 5.9.11 and Erlang 24.2 in windows 10. but unable to start, getting errors like below.

[image: ERROR LOG]

- Tried to edit rabbitmq-server.bat file as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323621/windows-x64-rabbitmq-install-error-with-erlang-environment-var-erlang-home), which is not working, so i restored default values

  Modified value:

  C:\Program Files\erl-24.2\erts-12.2\bin\erl.exe

[image: rabbitmq-server.bat]

- environment variable change was also done as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323621/windows-x64-rabbitmq-install-error-with-erlang-environment-var-erlang-home) which also not working.

[image: Environment variable]

[image: env variable set up]

Kindly let me know to resolve this issue?